# Set cell equal to formula after clicking VBA button

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set cell E1 equal to a formula after clicking a button. The formula that currently exists in this cell is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("ID",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH("*"&B1&"*",OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("Name",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),0)),"")
```

Essentially, I have a VBA button that fills down this formula in column E, based on the number of items in column B:

```
With Sheets("AssetName Sheet")
    .range("E1").AutoFill .range("E1:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Instead of just filling down the formula in E1, I want to set E1 equal to the formula and then fill down. I would like store the formula within my VBA button code, rather than in the cell itself.

Here is my attempt at it, but it didn't work.

```
.range("E1").Value = [IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("ID",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),MATCH("*"&B1&"*",OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH("Name",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),0)),"")]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look into [WorksheetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
'double-up any " inside the formula string...
Const F As String = "=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH(""ID"",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1)," & _
    "MATCH(""*""&B1&""*"",OFFSET('AMP Sheet'!$A:$A,,MATCH(""Name"",'AMP Sheet'!$1:$1,0)-1),0)),"""")"

With Sheets("AssetName Sheet")
    .Range("E1:E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = F
End With
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just added the fill down logic after the .Range and it's working just as excepted.

Comment: Should not need any additional fill down step?  The formula already fills the range in Col E...